# how to add comments box to iweb website?

Tags: iweb

is there a way to have comments box on a website made on Apple's iWeb. 
I don't host my website with Apple MobileMe. I just think it is too expensive. I have been hosting it with Godaddy.
But yesterday I found out the comment function built in iWeb only works if you are hosting your website with MobileMe.

I need something that blends in with my website properly, I wouldn't like to just smack something over my website that simply doesn't feel it belongs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are quite a few options out there...
but if you are going for the looks of it I would suggest:

[flexi comment box](http://alimsyed.com/flexicommentbox/Flexi_Comment_Box_v3.0.html).

It looks very nice and it can be customized, which means you can 'blend in' your pages very well... looking forward to your "blend" :P

Comment: thank you so much! I think this proved to be the best solution for my website, perfect for a noob like me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend DISQUS. They do a great box to add comments to your iweb site. You can just embed their code as an HTML snippet and it works great !